# CORS policy with images on my Apache Server with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, cors

Another day and another cors-policy problem. This is the first time I had Cors Policy problem with images.
I've faced a thousand times the problem of cors policy using both PHP for server side and Ajax and Jquery for the front-end, but with images I never had problem and I don't really understand how to solve this issue.

Server side this is my .htaccess (and work perfectly for rest request):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# CORS POLICY HERE
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And then this is how I sent through JS my rest request:

```
$.ajax({
    //url:"https://ayco.app/storage/profile_pics/users/andreacorriga.png",
    url: "https://ayco.app", 
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: async function(data){
        console.log(base64encode(data))
        alert("success")
    },  // success
    error: function(xhr, status){
        alert("error")
    } // error
})
```

In the JS example, I left two urls (one of which is commented out) for you to try. The one with the base url works perfectly because the cors policy is set correctly.
When I try to access an image instead I get the usual problem:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ayco.app/storage/profile_pics/users/andreacorriga.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Am I doing wrong? This is a server-side problem or client-side problem? Any Solution?

Comment: Is `https://ayco.app` a site you control? Are you setting the `.htaccess` rules of that domain?

Comment: Yes. I set that .htaccess I wrote

Comment: Are the headers present if you using postman?

Comment: Yes, Using postman or insomnia I see the `access-control-allow-origin`, `access-control-allow-headers` and `access-control-allow-methods` calling the image

Comment: To be clear, they are in the response from the server, not your request? And they are set to `*`, or the correct domain for the request source?

Comment: Yes.  It is possibile that the problem is the source of the request? localhost?

Comment: If you've set `*` as the allowed Origin then localhost is fine